# How to schedule a job in AWS to trigger a Lambda at 7:00PM everyday?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to schedule a job in AWS to trigger a Lambda at 7:00PM everyday?

My use-case is to send push notifications to specific users. I have users in India and US. After processing the DB to identify those users, I will publish the message using Firebase Admin SDK.

Comment: See [Creating an Amazon EventBridge rule that runs on a schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform this task using Amazon EventBridge and Cron Expressions.

Assume you have a Lambda function named employeemsg.

1. Choose the employeemsg function.
2. Under Designer, choose Add trigger.
3. Set the trigger type to CloudWatch Events/EventBridge.
4. For Rule, choose Create a new rule.
5. Fill in the Rule name and Rule description.
6. For rule type, select Schedule expression.
7. In the Schedule expression field, enter a cron expression. For
   example, cron(0 12 ? * MON-FRI *).
8. Choose Add.

Note: For more information, see [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon EventBridge (CloudWatch Events)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents.html).